# How to Convert image URL from server (API / ImageURL) to Base64 in Vue.Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

A lot of reference I see about this problem is about `upload file and convert to base64` but in my case I want to convert an Image URL from server and convert it to base64 but I still failed to do it, right now I tried it like this, but it still failed since it doesn't show anything

this is my html:

```
<div v-if="questionData">
    <img class="img-preview-download" :src="questionData.image_url? getBase64Image(questionData.image_url) : 'https://via.placeholder.com/640x360'" alt="img-preview">
</div>
```

this is my method:

```
getBase64Image(img) {
    console.log("cek base64 : ", btoa(img));
    return `data:image/jpeg;base64,${btoa(img)}`;
},
```

I read some using file reader but isn't it only for file when you upload a data using `input`? can someone help me to solve this? I'm using Vue.Js for the framework

when I used this method I got result like this:

[image: Image crash, as you can see]

Comment: What is inside that variable `image_url`? If it's URL string (something like `https://mypage.io/image.png`) then converting it to base64 would require You to get its content by an AJAX call first, and then convert that blob to base64.

Comment: @JanMadeyski Thankyou for your response, Sorry I forgot to mention it, in variable `image_url` it is a an image file I get from a server (External image file), and it seems `btoa()` only change the string and not the file itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is my answer for my future self, who might be forget and stumble again in this problem!

You can solve it by making a new image and inside that image file, you can add your `src` so the image can be process when still loading or `onload`.

**Remember!**

Since it is you, You might be remove the last `image.src = url` to get a clean code, but this is important, if you remove that line, `image.onload` will not be trigger because it will search for the image source. and if you try to use `image.srcObject` to put it with `mediaStream` it will give you `Resolution Overloaded` since you still not find the answer for this problem, it is okay, you can use the image first since your step is to achieve `how to get file from Image URL`. so this is the method you use to solve this problem:

```
downloadPreview() {
    const el = this.$refs.printMe;
    const options = {
        type: 'dataURL'
    };

    this.$html2canvas(el, options).then(data => {
        this.output = data;

        const a = document.createElement('a');
        a.style.display = 'none';
        a.href = data;

        // this is just optional function to download your file
        a.download = `name.jpeg`;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
    });
},

convertImgUrlToBase64(url) {
    let self = this;
    var image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous'); // use it if you try in a different origin of your web

    image.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;

        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);

        canvas.toBlob(
            function(source) {
                var newImg = document.createElement("img"),
                url = URL.createObjectURL(source);

                newImg.onload = function() {
                // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                };

                newImg.src = url;
            },
            "image/jpeg",
            1
        );

        // If you ever stumble at 18 DOM Exception, just use this code to fix it
        // let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
        let dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        console.log("cek inside url : ", url);

        if(url === backgroundImg) {
            self.assignImageBase64Background(dataUrl);
        } else {
            self.assignImageBase64(dataUrl);
        }
    };
    image.src = url;
},

assignImageBase64(img) {
    this.imgBase64 = img;
},
```

just for information, I use this library to change the `div` into `image` file:
[vue-html2canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-html2canvas)

Notes:

If you ever wondering why I give `self.assignImageBase64(dataUrl);` this function in the end, this is because I still wondering how onload works, and how to return `Base64` url to the parent thats why I just assign it again in another function since it easier to do.